# Function failing to return a value

Tags: node.js, function, return, steganography

So I'm making a simple steganography tool (encrypting messages within images) and exposing it as a web service via Node.js. I am very new to Javascript and Node.js in particular. The app first converts a text string into a binary string by changing each character into an 8-bit ASCII encoding, resulting in one large binary string. I then encrypt the message within the pixels. Even values of pixels represent 0s from the binary, and odd values represent 1s. The end of the string is marked as 3 pixels of value 100 in a row (this is temporary, until I figure out a better way to mark the end). I'm using a node.js library called 'pngjs' that gives me pixel-level access to png images.

So I have a problem with the decodeMessage function. It builds up the string message, and is then meant to return it, however the return call at the end results in undefined.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
function encodeMessage(image, mes) {

    var message = mes;

    var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

    fs.createReadStream(image)
    .pipe(new PNG({
        filterType: 4
    }))
    .on('parsed', function() {

        for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                var idx = (this.width * y + x);// << 2;
                //console.log(idx); 
                if (idx < message.length) {

                    var item = message.charAt(idx);

                    /* if the character in the encoded string is 0 */
                    if (item == 0) {
                        /* if the pixel is odd, we want it to be even */
                        if (this.data[idx] % 2 == 1) {
                        /* if the pixel is 0, add 1 to it */
                        if (this.data[idx] == 0) {
                            this.data[idx] = this.data[idx] + 1;
                        } else {
                            /* else substract 1 */
                            this.data[idx] = this.data[idx] - 1;
                        }
                        }
                    } else {
                        /* if the character in the encoded string is 1 */
                        if (this.data[idx] % 2 == 0) {
                        if (this.data[idx] == 0) {
                            this.data[idx] = this.data[idx] + 1;
                        } else {
                            this.data[idx] = this.data[idx] - 1;
                        }
                        }
                    }

                    //console.log(this.data[idx]);

                } else if (idx === message.length) {

                    /* do something to the first pixel following the end of the string */
                    this.data[idx] = 100;
                    this.data[idx+1] = 100;
                    this.data[idx+2] = 100;
                    //console.log(this.data[idx]);

                } else {

                    /* do something to the remaining pixels */

                }                  
            }
        }
        this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('encoded_' + image));
    });
}

function decodeMessage(image) {
    var message = "";

    var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

    fs.createReadStream(image)
    .pipe(new PNG({
        filterType: 4
    }))
    .on('parsed', function() {


        dance:
        for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
            for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {

                var idx = (this.width * y + x);// << 2;

                if (this.data[idx] == 100 && this.data[idx+1] == 100 && this.data[idx+2] == 100) {
                    break dance;
                } else {

                    if (this.data[idx] % 2 == 0) {
                        message += "0";
                    } else {
                        message += "1";
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        /* the message outputs correctly over here */
        console.log(message);
        //return message;
    });

    /* but the return of the variable here doesn't work */
    return message;
}

exports.encodeMessage = encodeMessage;
exports.decodeMessage = decodeMessage;
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parsed` event is fired asynchronously, so you cannot return a value from `decodeMessage`.

```
function decodeMessage(image, cb) {

  // Code
  .on('parsed', function() {
    // Code

    console.log(message);
    cb(message);
  });
}
```

Then you must pass a callback to your `decodeMessage` function.

```
decodeMessage(image, function(decoded){
  // Here is the decoded data.
});
```

The same is true for your `encodeMessage` function. The function will return before encoding has finished. If you want to know when it is done, you need to pass a callback the same way.

Comment: Thanks! I now understand the concepts behind asynchronous functions. I'm still struggling to get the function to return the 'message' string. The functions in this .js module are exported to another module and are called there. I need to return the 'message' string to an outside variable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @DinislamTebuev No prob! The issue is that because it is asynchronous, you cannot return anything useful. Instead, you need to pass a callback in, and make any code that calls decodeMessage also asynchronous. Asynchronous is viral in that, if you want to call anything that is asynchronous then to use it properly you need to make all of your own code async too. If you are using the module functions, I can expand with more examples.

Comment: That'd be great! I'm splitting my code into modules to follow a good programming style. My server.js file will be calling these functions and it needs to handle multiple requests at once, so as I understand everything needs to be asynchronous

Comment: Basically you want to call the function and pass a callback just like my second snippet.